# Cannot delete a chat message via Slack API

Tags: slack-api, slack

I have a Slack team with a public channel.
My goal is to use the channel only for announcements posted by bot-A.

I understand that it is not possible to configure Slack channel to be writable for only one person and read-only for the rest, I created a bot-B (Python thing running on an external machine) that monitors the channel via RTM and if there is any message not coming from bot-A, bot-B's task is to delete the message by calling chat.delete (https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete). Bot-B is also in the channel.

Unfortunately bot-B is getting "cant_delete_message" which, according to the chat.delete doc, means that he has no permissions.

However, according to https://api.slack.com/bot-users, chat.delete is allowed for Custom Bots.

So is my bot-B not a "Custom Bot"? If so, what does a Custom Bot actually is and how can I create one?

Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a Slack user (bot or otherwise) is only allowed to delete its own messages. There's no way to delete messages posted by someone else.

**EDIT**: I stand corrected. Admins can delete other people's messages. From https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202395258-Editing-or-deleting-messages:

> Owners and Admins can delete messages from any sender as long as the messages are in public or private channels that the Owner or Admin has joined.

Comment: So how does https://www.stacktodo.com/tools/block work? (No personal exp. with it, it was recommended to me as a workaround to read-only channels in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906472/read-only-slack-channel). And at least the channel admin can delete other user's messages.

Comment: @RadekS Yes, I stand corrected! Admins can do this. It looks like stacktodo requires admin permission: https://slack-files.com/T096T9C4S-F0CBZKV2T-d0af31523a.

Comment: So is the answer to this question that Bot B just needs to be authed by an admin user? @RadekS