# Deleting Messages in Slack

Tags: python, slack-api

Sooo, I'm relatively new to programming, and trying to learn how to consume API's. I figured I would start out by building a Slack bot for moderation purposes since I use Slack a lot. For the most part, everything works except for when I try to delete a message. The API returns saying it can't find the message even though it is there in the channel (the slack API uses timestamps to locate said message). The timestamps match, but proclaims the message doesn't exist. Here is my code:

````
def __init__(self, token):
    self.token = token
    self.users = {}
    self.channels = {}
    self.slack = SlackClient(self.token)
    self.as_user = True

def connect(self):
    if self.slack.rtm_connect():
        self.post_message('#test', "*AUTOMOD* _v0.1_")

        while True:
            # print(self.slack.rtm_read())
            self.parse_data(self.slack.rtm_read())
            time.sleep(1)

def parse_data(self, payload):
    if payload:
        if payload[0]['type'] == 'message':
            print(("user: {} message: {} channel: {}").format(payload[0]['user'], payload[0]['text'], payload[0]['channel']))
            self.handle_message(payload[0])

def handle_message(self, data):
    # these users can post whatever they want.
    WHITELISTED = ["U4DU2TS2F", "U3VSRJJD8", "U3WLZUTQE", "U3W1Q2ULT"]

    # get userid
    sent_from = (data['user'])

    # ignore whitelisted
    if sent_from in WHITELISTED:
        return

    # if message was sent from someone not in WHITELISTED, delete it
    else:
        print(("\n\ntimestamp of message: {}").format(data['ts']))
        self.delete_message(data['channel'], data['ts'])
        self.post_message(data['channel'], "```" + random.choice(dongers) + "```")


def delete_message(self, channel, timestamp):
    print(("deleting message in channel '{}'...").format(channel))
    print("timestamp check (just to make sure): ", timestamp)
    deleted = self.slack.api_call("chat.delete",
                        channel=channel,
                        timestamp=timestamp,
                        as_user=self.as_user
                    )

    if deleted.get('ok'):
        print("\nsuccessfully deleted.\n")
    else:
        print(("\ncouldn't delete message: {}\n").format(deleted['error']))
````

*OUTPUT*

```
timestamp of message:                    1488822718.000040
deleting message in channel:             'G4DGYCW2X'
timestamp check (just to make sure...):  1488822718.000040

couldn't delete message: message_not_found
```

Any ideas on what could be happening? Here is the [chat.delete](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete) method for context.

EDIT:

Due @pvg's recommendation of "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example", I have placed the ENTIRE code from the project in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/notdom/e3513c6869019ed93272139981ed27b7).

Comment: You should try to write this up as a [MCVE]. It's not really clear, for instance, that the message has posted when your `handle_message` method gets called, however it gets called.

Comment: @pvg woah, nice doc. Do you think it would be better to post it all in a gist?

Comment: No, that's kind of the point of 'minimal'. Also the code actually has to be in your question. So optimal question has a self-contained code snippet that shows the problem you're running into and others can try. Not always possible but probably is in this case. Another positive side effect: writing one of these often lets you figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: @pvg I get what you're saying, but the code I posted in the original question is the culprit and the most minimal amount of code (it's literally the only part of my bot that doesn't work). Regardless, I have bookmarked your link because it seems like a great resource!

Comment: It's not self contained. For instance, there is no way to tell from the code in your question how you're actually receiving the message.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/37923772/3901060. It's possible your bot can't delete messages posted by someone else.

Comment: @FamousJameous well, similar, but not the problem. It's not that it can't delete messages (it can, it has admin privileges), it just proclaims that it can't find it even though I am using the supplied timestamp it returns

Comment: The answer below seems right, as well as the fact that messages are not immediately available for deletion - you may have to wait and retry. As an example for next time, here's what a possible [MCVE] would look like for your problem. Note it's self-contained (i.e. you can run it yourself right away) and shorter than the code you posted. https://gist.github.com/pvg/287a66bfa49a8319ce1ce6ad7fb04009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue might be that you appear to be passing a `timestamp` parameter to `chat.delete`, when the API method takes a `ts` parameter instead. ([See docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete#arguments))